# Switching Image on segment click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I started objective C today and for the last hour I've been trying to work out how to switch an image when I click a button, It's a segmenting button with 2 segments, first segment *should* load 0.jpg, second segment should load 1.jpg.

I can get it to change from 0->1 but not back, so it's as if only the first switch is being registered, any ideas?

(As you can see, i've tried debugging, everything should check out:

```
2012-05-25 13:22:31.173 Clock2[3398:f803] Segment clicked: 0
2012-05-25 13:22:31.174 Clock2[3398:f803] 0.jpg
2012-05-25 13:22:31.367 Clock2[3398:f803] Segment clicked: 1
2012-05-25 13:22:31.368 Clock2[3398:f803] 1.jpg
```

.

```
- (IBAction)clockselect:(id)sender {
    NSString* segindex= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", clockselectout.selectedSegmentIndex];
    NSString* type= @".jpg";
    NSString* filename= [segindex stringByAppendingString:type ];
    if (clockselectout.selectedSegmentIndex == '0') {
       NSLog(@"Segment clicked: %d", clockselectout.selectedSegmentIndex);
       // NSLog(filename);
        [clockimg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: filename]]; 
    } else {
       NSLog(@"Segment clicked: %d", clockselectout.selectedSegmentIndex);
       // NSLog(filename);
        [clockimg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: filename]]; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)segmentControleChanged
 {

  switch(self.yourSegmet.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {

        case 0:
         [clockimg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"image1"]];
         break;

          case 1:
          [clockimg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"]];
           break;

            default:
             break;
       }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you must use

```
if (clockselectout.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
```

to compare int value.

You always can swap from 0 to 1 because

```
if (clockselectout.selectedSegmentIndex == '0') {
```

is always false ;)

Comment: @Jamie Taylor: I think you got it. you were comparing against an `NSString` not an `int`

Answer (score 0):

If only == was the problem then in log it should not have printed

2012-05-25 13:22:31.367 Clock2[3398:f803] Segment clicked: 1
2012-05-25 13:22:31.368 Clock2[3398:f803] 1.jpg

because if it was not entering in that block then it should not have printed above log.Am I correct?Then how you was getting above log?

Comment: OP never said that == was the problem?